# Not displaying cards

Tags: java, enums, instance, encapsulation

I am creating an instance deck of cards that should display all 52 cards when built, then it should shuffle the cards and deal 5. After this the menu should prompt for either another 5 to be dealt, or the deck to be reshuffled, which adds all the drawn cards back in, or to exit the application. However, when I run the app, it just displays null for all 52 cards, and each card that is dealt. The application worked and almost met all the specification before I talked with my instructor, and what I have now is where I got during/ after our talk. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and could really use the help. Just for clarification I will post the requirements, then the code. I appreciate the help.

```
At startup, it constructs a Deck of Cards
52 distinct cards running from Ace - King, of suit Heart, Club, Diamond, or Spade
Shuffle the cards!!
For proof, print out all 52 cards to the console in a useful, readable way.
Then, deal the top five cards to the console (meaning print them to the console)
After all of this, allow the user choose between dealing the next five cards, reshuffling the deck, or quitting the application. 
If the user chooses to deal the next 5 cards, do so based on which cards have not yet been dealt. DO NOT RESHUFFLE.
If the user chooses to reshuffle, simply repeat the process of shuffling, printing the deck, and dealing the top five cards.
If the user chooses to quit the application, simply end the app.
```

The code I'm practicing encapsulation so I will post each class broken up as is in eclipse.

Driver

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        DeckRun.run();

        }

    }
```

DeckRun

```
    public class DeckRun {

    static Card[] d1 = new Card[52];

    public static void run() throws IOException {

        printDeck();
        System.out.println("");
        Deal.dealCards(d1);
        System.out.println("");
        menu();

    }

    public static void printDeck() {

    for (Card c : d1) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    }

    public static void menu() throws IOException{

        BufferedReader readRacer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int menu = 0;

        do {

        System.out.println("Press 1 to be dealt 5 random cards.");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to shuffle all the cards back into the deck.");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to quit the application.");

        String input = readRacer.readLine();
        menu = Integer.parseInt(input);

        switch (menu) {

        case 1: Deal.dealCards(d1);
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("The deck has been shuffled.");
                Deck[] d1 = new Deck[52];
            break;
        case 3: System.out.println("I'm not bad, I'm just drawn that way.");
            break;
        }
        } while (menu != 3);
    }

}
```

Card

```
public class Card {

    private Rank rank; // Variable to assign a card its rank.
    private Suit suit; // Variable to assign a card its suit.

    public Card (Rank rank, Suit suit) { // Constructor to build a card.
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public Rank getRank() { // Retrieves the card's rank from the enum Rank.
        return rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() { // Retrieves the card's suit from the enum Suit.
        return suit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { //
        return rank + " OF " + suit;
    }

}
```

Deck

```
public class Deck {

    private Card[] cards;

    public Deck() {

        int numberOfRanks = 13;
        int numberOfSuits = 4;
        int numberOfCards = numberOfRanks * numberOfSuits;

        Rank[] rank = Rank.values();
        Suit[] suit = Suit.values();

        cards = new Card[numberOfCards];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRanks; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSuits; j++) {

                cards[j * numberOfRanks + i] = new Card(rank[i], suit[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffleCards() {

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int c = rand.nextInt(6) + 5; c > 0; c--) {
            for (int i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

                int index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
                Card card = cards[index];
                cards[index] = cards[i];
                cards[i] = card;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Deal

```
public class Deal {

    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void dealCards(Card[] d1) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(d1[counter]);
            if (counter == 50) {
                System.out.println("Almost all cards have been used, please reshuffle.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rank (Enum)

```
public enum Rank { ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT,
NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, }
```

Suit (Enum)

```
public enum Suit { CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES, }
```

Not really sure where the issue is, but what I've changed today is after realizing I need an instance of the deck, my professor helped me understand that instead of a method for the deck of cards in class Deck, i needed a constructor. I believe I'm going down the right path but I am just utterly stumped. Any help is appreciated and if you can explain my errors so I may learn and progress even more thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys. The answer was simple. I deleted the deal class, and moved the method to the deck class. I initialized the counter as a private, class-level int, which fixed the repetition issue.  I will post the finished code below, so you can see.

DeckRun Class

```
public class DeckRun {

    static Deck d1 = new Deck();

    public static void run() throws IOException {

        printDeck();
        System.out.println("");
        d1.dealCards();
        System.out.println("");
        menu();

    }

    public static void printDeck() {

        System.out.println(d1.toString());
    }


    public static void menu() throws IOException{

        BufferedReader readRacer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int menu = 0;

        do {

        System.out.println("Press 1 to be dealt 5 random cards.");
        System.out.println("Press 2 to shuffle all the cards back into the deck.");
        System.out.println("Press 3 to quit the application.");

        String input = readRacer.readLine();
        menu = Integer.parseInt(input);

        switch (menu) {

        case 1: d1.dealCards();
        System.out.println("");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("The deck has been shuffled.");
                    d1.shuffleCards();
                    System.out.println("");
            break;
        case 3: System.out.println("I'm not bad, I'm just drawn that way.");
            break;
        }
        } while (menu != 3);
    }

}
```

Deck Class

```
public class Deck {

    private Card[] cards;

    public Deck() {

        int numberOfRanks = 13;
        int numberOfSuits = 4;
        int numberOfCards = numberOfRanks * numberOfSuits;

        Rank[] rank = Rank.values();
        Suit[] suit = Suit.values();

        cards = new Card[numberOfCards];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRanks; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSuits; j++) {

                cards[i * numberOfSuits + j] = new Card(rank[i], suit[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void shuffleCards() {

        Random rand = new Random();
        counter = 0;

        for (int c = rand.nextInt(6) + 5; c > 0; c--) {
            for (int i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

                int index = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
                Card card = cards[index];
                cards[index] = cards[i];
                cards[i] = card;
            }
        }
    }

    private int counter = 0;

    public void dealCards() {

        try{
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println(cards[counter]);
            if (counter == 50) {
                System.out.println("Almost all cards have been used, please reshuffle.");
                // Either return 1 card or an array of 5 cards.
            }
        } 
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe){
            System.out.println("Caught an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Reshuffling deck.");
            shuffleCards();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String deckOfCards = "";

        for (Card c : cards) {

            deckOfCards += c.toString() + "\n";

        }

        return deckOfCards;

    }
}
```

That is all I had to fix, but I appreciate the help. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` you are calling `DeckRun.run()`, let's take a look at your definition of this method. It calls `printDeck` which iterates over an array of cards (`d1`), which is never populated. That's why you are getting a bunch of `NULL`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DeckRun` should have an instance of `Deck` instead of cards array

```
 public class DeckRun {
    private Deck deck = new Deck();
    public static void run() throws IOException {
        printDeck();
        System.out.println("");
        Deal.dealCards(deck.getCards());
        System.out.println("");
        menu();
    }
    public static void printDeck() {
       for (Card c : deck.getCards()) {
           System.out.println(c);
       }
    }

    public static void menu() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader readRacer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int menu = 0;
        do {
           System.out.println("Press 1 to be dealt 5 random cards.");
           System.out.println("Press 2 to shuffle all the cards back into the deck.");
           System.out.println("Press 3 to quit the application.");
           String input = readRacer.readLine();
           menu = Integer.parseInt(input);
           switch (menu) {
             case 1: 
                Deal.dealCards(deck.getCards());
                break;
             case 2: 
                System.out.println("The deck has been shuffled.");
                deck.shuffleCards();
                break;
             case 3: 
                System.out.println("I'm not bad, I'm just drawn that way.");
                break;
           }
        } while (menu != 3);
    }
}
```

you also need to add a getter for cards in Deck

Comment: I will give this a go, however I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean. Nevertheless I will examine this and do what I can.

Comment: So going through this and some other tweaking i've done, I now have everything working except the no repeating rule. Also, I don't what to do with the shuffle option. I was thinking I should create a new instance of deck, however then i'd need a way to replace every command that called the first instance with the second... I'm so lost and confused right now..

Answer (score 0):

so your problem lays in this loop

```
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRanks; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSuits; j++) {

            cards[j * numberOfRanks + i] = new Card(rank[i], suit[j]);
        }
    }
```

J*numOfRanks +i is basically saying 0*4 = 0+0 = 0

and so on, causing problems. To make this simpler i would recommend a 2D array, making 4 columns for the suits and 13 rows for the ranks then a similar loop would work perfectly. please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I'm still learning, I've only been coding for about 6 weeks, so I'm not familiar with what a 2D array is, sorry. However before I changed the frame of this to a constructor from an array it worked fine, so I'm confused why it wouldn't work now.